# Is multiple database files less efficient than one with multiple tables?(SQLite3&Node.js)

Tags: sql, node.js, database, sqlite

As the title says, is it more efficient to use one .db file or is there not a large effect?  As I assume this would relate to read-write calls I feel it is worth mentioning this will run on a Linux environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has yet answered, I will answer it by saying multiple files is more efficient in some scenarios as it can cause much slower file transfer/copy speeds.  Other than that it seems to be basically the same.

To add to that, multiple database files would also be slightly larger as they would need more file headers